# Queue class using generators

Tags: javascript, generator

I'm trying to create a queue class using generators but nothing I try seems to work.  Below is the code that I wrote to try to accomplish what I want to do but it doesn't seem to wait for each promise to resolve.  It just iterates through the queue and instantiates the next promise without waiting for the previous one to resolve -- it's not waiting for the `yield` to return control.

```
class BroadcastQueueHandler {
  #broadcastQueue;
  #metaData;

  constructor() {
    this.#broadcastQueue = [];
  }

  setItems(aBroadcasts) {
    this.#broadcastQueue = aBroadcasts;
  }

  setMetaData(oMetaData) {
    this.#metaData = Object.assign({}, oMetaData);
  }

  runBroadcast(oBroadcast) {
    const oThis = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const aBroadcasts = [oBroadcast];
      const oBroadcastHandler = BroadcastHandler.factory(aBroadcasts);
      if (oBroadcastHandler !== null) {
        const oMetaData = Object.assign({}, oThis.#metaData);
        let fOnClick = function () {};

        if (typeof oMetaData.onClick === 'function') {
          fOnClick = oMetaData.onClick;
        }
        oMetaData.onClick = function () {
          fOnClick();
          resolve(oBroadcast);
        };

        oBroadcastHandler.setItems(aBroadcasts);
        oBroadcastHandler.setMetaData(oMetaData);
        oBroadcastHandler.run();
      }
    });
  }

  *processQueue() {
    for (const oBroadcast of this.#broadcastQueue) {
      yield this.runBroadcast(oBroadcast);
    }
  }

  run() {
    for (const result of this.processQueue()) {
      console.log('result', result);
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why isn't the `yield` waiting for the promise returned by `runBroadcast` to resolve?

Comment: "*Why isn't the yield waiting for the promise returned by runBroadcast to resolve?*" why would it? `yield` just produces the result as the next value from the generator. If you give it a promise it produces a promise as the next value. Why should it handle promises any differently?

Comment: You can check this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947850/what-happens-when-promise-is-yielded-in-javascript

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915545/why-can-yield-not-resolve-promise

Comment: `for...of` loop in the run method is not waiting for the promises returned by the generator function `processQueue` to resolve.

Comment: @JishanShaikh, then how should the `run()` be changed?  I tried changing that method so that it was `async` and using `await` but when I executed that method, nothing happened -- none of my breakpoints were hit.

Comment: Something along the lines of: ```async run() {
  const generator = this.processQueue();
  let result = generator.next();
  while (!result.done) {
    console.log('result', await result.value);
    result = generator.next();
  }
}
```. Can you edit your async/await'ed `run()` so that we can see?

Comment: @JishanShaikh, that worked.  I'm still trying to learn how to work with generators.  Specifically the interaction between generators and promises.  So far, as you can see, my efforts haven't worked out for me.  Changing the code to implement your suggestion worked great!  Thank you very much!  I'm just not sure _*why*_ it worked.  What's the difference between doing it that way and setting it up as part of a `for` loop?  If I use the `for` loop, why is it the case that `run` doesn't actually execute?

Comment: The best answer I can give is "this is by design". The difference between using a for loop and a while loop with the next method (of the generator object) to iterate over a generator function that yields promises is due to the way these loops handle asynchronous code. A for loop is not designed to handle asynchronous code, while a while loop with an async function and the await keyword to handle asynchronous code within the loop. which is what we did here. I'm a little fuzzy on the details, but that is the gist of it.

Comment: @JishanShaikh, learn something new every day.  Thank you very much for your replies!  I really appreciate them.